# Accessing Tomcat context parameter in Camel REST dsl

Tags: spring, rest, tomcat, servlets, apache-camel

I am currently working on a set of REST resources that are deployed in a Tomcat servlet container. I have been using the Camel REST dsl (kickstarted by Spring) and it works very well. Now, I would like to get access to some parameters specified in the container's context.xml but havn't been able to figure out how to do that as I do not have access to the Servlet context in my route builder. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are hosting your Spring-app on Tomcat, Camel is using a separate, internally loaded web server implementation for it's REST endpoints, e.g. Restlet or Spark-rest (for more infos check [here](https://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html)). For that reason your Camel route is ignorant and entirely disconnected to your Tomcat let alone its Servlets contexts.

Comment: So to achieve what I am trying to I am left with System properties?

Comment: System Properties or .properties config files. You can use spring beans in your camel root and inject configuration values with @Value into them.